# Spring boot + Hibernate + Wildfly .. Log SQL statements and it's binding PARAMETERS

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I have the mentioned above setup and I have a big issues to log SQL binding parameters, I got it working to log the Query with the below configurations in application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

And for logging the binding parameters values I tried the following properties but no luck to get it working.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.SQL=debug
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=debug
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
```

So, is there something I am missing here, and is there a config can solve this? (Java config or Properties?) or I have to go for something to intercept the datasource like P6SPY?

Sample from console log:

```
15:09:42,116 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Hibernate: 
15:09:42,117 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     select
15:09:42,117 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         * 
15:09:42,117 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     from
15:09:42,117 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         ( select
15:09:42,117 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.NOTIFICATION_ID as notification_id1_27_,
15:09:42,117 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.COMMENT_ID_REF as comment_id_ref2_27_,
15:09:42,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.CREATED_AT as created_at3_27_,
15:09:42,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.DESCRIPTION_AR as description_ar4_27_,
15:09:42,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.DESCRIPTION_EN as description_en5_27_,
15:09:42,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.IDEA_ID_REF as idea_id_ref6_27_,
15:09:42,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.INITIATOR_ID as initiator_id7_27_,
15:09:42,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.NOTIFICATION_NAME as notification_name8_27_,
15:09:42,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ID as notification_type_9_27_,
15:09:42,118 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.IS_READ as is_read10_27_,
15:09:42,119 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.TEAM_ID_REF as team_id_ref11_27_,
15:09:42,119 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.USER_PROFILE_ID as user_profile_id12_27_ 
15:09:42,119 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         from
15:09:42,119 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             OQ_IDEATE.NOTIFICATIONS_VIEW notificati0_ 
15:09:42,119 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         where
15:09:42,119 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)             notificati0_.USER_PROFILE_ID=? ) 
15:09:42,120 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     where
15:09:42,120 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)         rownum <= ?
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: I think, you should go for P6SPY,  it would save lot of headache but don't use logging in production.

Comment: @code_mechanic I will go for it for now, but I am still thinking that there is a better way to do this task. And of course, I won't apply it in production. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE